# Getting coverage xml for a python file run with spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, code-coverage, spark-submit

I have a python file (`myfile.py`) that I typically run by running a command like

```
spark2-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client myfile.py arg1 arg2
```

I need to get coverage on this file, and I have been trying things like

```
coverage run myfile.py arg1 arg2
coverage xml -o coverage-myfile.xml
```

This works fine and gives me the coverage xml, but so lines don't work properly as it needs to be run using `spark-submit`, not simply `python`. Therefore, my coverage is a little lower than I would like.

Is there a way to do this but using spark?

Answer (score 0):

In a test environment (so it's not perfectly one-to-one, but should be similar), I've done this by implementing a session-wide fixture that builds a `SparkSession`. Something like:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def spark():
    spark = (
        # In place for Spark 3.x to work.
        SparkSession.builder.config(
            "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions",
            "-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true",
        )
        .config(
            "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions",
            "-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true",
        )
        .appName("pytest-provider-test")
        .master("local[2]")
        .getOrCreate()
    )
    return spark
```

Then, for all the functions I need to test (and coverage on), use the `spark` fixture.

In your case, you may need to have a test/coverage-specific module call a relevant starting function in `myfile.py` with a `SparkSession` object built as above, and pass that down through your codebase. Your coverage would still be accurate for those functions and any submodules.

This can then be run as a regular python module.